How to convert spark dataframe to pandas dataframe and save it in csv
I have this sql query and I am running it in spark cluster jupyter notebook:
val df1 = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("query", """
    select *
    from table1
    where col1 >= '2024-04-01' 
    and col2 = 'pp' 
    limit 5000 
    """).load()
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("fact1")

spark.sql("""
         select *
         from fact1
          """).show(true)

But its not exactly as pandas dataframe so that I can apply pandas dataframe operations and save it in csv.
I tried this also:
val result_df: DataFrame = spark.sql("""
         select *
         from fact1
          """).toDF()

result_df.show(true)

But still not exactly in pandas dataframe.

df.toPandas() will convert spark dataframe to pandas dataframe.
Spark framework uses distributed mechanism for operation whereas pandas will not use distributed mechanism which can impact performace when the data is huge.

:29: error: value toPandas is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
result_df.toPandas()
^

As you are using SCALA to read spark dataframe you need to enable spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") and then toPandas() will work

:29: error: value toPandas is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toPandas'?
""").toPandas()
